# L'abréviation « etc » entre parenthèses

Tags: typographie, ponctuation, abréviations

Quand j'ai une énumération se terminant par « etc » entre parenthèses, je ne sais pas si je doit ajouter un point après la parenthèse fermante. Par exemple :

> OpenGL est une bibliothèque utilisée dans de nombreux domaines (jeu-vidéo, conception assistée par ordinateur, etc.). Dans ce chapitre, nous aborderons [...]

Comme vous le voyez, j'ai ajouté un point après la parenthèse fermante pour terminer la phrase. Est-ce correct ou ce point est inutile ?

Answer (score 5):

Si *etc.* est en fin de phrase, on n'ajoute pas un autre point. Ils se confondent.

En revanche, *etc.* à l'intérieur d'une parenthèse doit avoir son point, et la phrase elle-même le sien (à l'extérieur de la parenthèse).

voir sur [Cordial cet exemple](http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/P_PARENT.htm).

Comment: Une autre source pour confirmer cette réponse: http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4113.